# How does 2nd for loop affect code? Harvard cs50

Tags: c, cs50

Purpose of code is to create a 'n by n' block of "#"

How does indenting the 2nd 'for loop' create the rows and column necessary?

I noticed that 'print ("\n");' also will lead to the desired outcome to create a 'n by n' block of "#". How?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
         n = get_int("Size: ");
    }
    while (n < 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This already works though right?

Comment: Yep it does! @V0_1D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indenting code is just to make it more readable. you could put al this on one line and it would still run, but please don't.

'\n' is just to go to the next line.

I'm not sure if this answers you're questions, because you're kind of unclear.

Comment: Ok, I was confused so as to how then when you execute the code, you would essentially get a 'n by n' of "#". I simply could not follow the logic here but your remarks helped.

Thank you! @V0_1D